# Recursive function in Python coming up with: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, recursion, sum

This function, that I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991348/how-to-write-this-sum-of-a-sum-recursively-in-python), is as follows:

```
def f(n, p, k, t):
    return sum(sum(1 if n == 3 else
                   (0 if k == 1 else
                    (1/36) * f(n-1, p, k-1, t-(max(p,i)))
                    for i in xrange(1, 7)))
                   for p in xrange(1, 7))

print sum(f(5,j,3,15) for j in xrange(1, 7))
```

When I run this, I get this long traceback error sequence ending in:

```
File "C:/Users/r/Documents/school/IB/Computer Science HL/Other Languages/Problem240/Problem240 - recursive2.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
for p in xrange(1, 7))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can someone please tell me what's going on? What is wrong with my code and how would I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I have a feeling that it's about the parenthesis

Comment: There really is no reason to write this as one giant expression. Are you just looking for "what did I get wrong here?" or "How can I organize this in a way that's readable enough for me to debug myself?"

Answer (score 2):

i think you mean

```
def f(n, p, k, t):
    return sum(sum(1 if n == 3 else
                   (0 if k == 1 else
                    (1/36) * f(n-1, p, k-1, t-(max(p,i)))) # <- more here
                   for i in range(1, 7)) # <- less here
               for p in range(1, 7))

print(sum(f(5,j,3,15) for j in range(1, 7)))
```

(i'm using python 3, but it's basically the same).

you have some parens wrong so the inner sum isn't a generator expression like you expect.

**also see gnibbler's point below since you're using python 2**

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was the problem with the parentheses. I just put the extra one in the wrong place. :D

Comment: `(1.0/36)` for Python2 to force float division

Answer (score 1):

If you can't understand your own code, break it down into smaller parts

```
def f(n, p, k, t):
    ternary = (1 if n == 3 else 0 if k == 1 else 
        f(n-1, p, k-1, t-max(p,i))/36.0 for i in range(1, 7))

    inner_sum = sum(ternary)
    return sum(inner_sum for p in range(1, 7))
```